# What does 'driving force of the engine' mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I am given this question: A truck of mass $2000\ \rm kg$ accelerates from $5\ \rm m/s$ to $20\ \rm m/s$ in $5\ \rm s$. Then i am asked to find the driving force of the engine. So, what does driving force means and is there a difference between finding a force and finding a driving force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just supposed to find the force $F$ that is responsible for accelerating the truck, $F=ma$.  The presence of "driving" does not really contribute anything here.